# Referencing assemblies in Windows Phone 8.1 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

what do I have to reference in Windows Phone 8.1 project under Visual Studio 2015 for Linq, ObservableCollection etc.?

I'm getting this error, **but only in the Watch window!**:

> groups error CS0012: The type 'IGrouping<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

But this assembly is not builded for Windows Universal Apps. So what assembly package should I reference? Same is for the ObservableCollection<>

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI;

namespace GoodCode.GTDApp.Models
{
    public class PageModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }

        public PageModel()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemModel>();
            this.Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var groups = this.Items.GroupBy(s => s.Date);
            foreach (var group in groups.OrderByDescending(s => s.First().Date))
            {
                foreach (var item in group)
                {
                    item.Color = Colors.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code where you use `IGrouping`? I have tried it on my WP 8.1 project and it works.

Comment: Well, the weird thing is, it is working, but this error it is throwing only in Watch window. See the edit.

Comment: Any resolutions for this?